# In Ruby, what's the relationship between 'new' and 'initialize'? How to return nil while initializing?

Tags: ruby, constructor, return, new-operator, initializer

What I want is:

```
obj = Foo.new(0)  # => nil or false
```

This doesn't work:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(val)
    return nil if val == 0
  end
end
```

I know in C/C++/Java/C#, we cant return a value in a constructor.

But I'm wondering whether it is possible in Ruby.

Comment: If this is a sanity check, a friendlier thing to do would be to raise an Exception explaining *why* you're not continuing the initialization.  Returning nil is just going to create (serious) confusion. Nobody would ever expect a newly instantiated object to be nil ;)

Comment: There are no constructors in `C`.

Comment: The notable exception to @d11wtq's statement would be `NilClass.new()`.

Comment: You should mark @Jörg W Mittag's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 91):

> In Ruby, what's the relationship between '`new`' and '`initialize`'?

`new` typically calls `initialize`. The default implementation of `new` is something like:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate

    obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    # actually, this is obj.send(:initialize, …) because initialize is private

    obj
  end
end
```

But you can, of course, override it to do anything you want.

> How to return nil while initializing?
>
> What I want is:
>
> ```
> obj = Foo.new(0)  # => nil or false
> ```
>
> This doesn't work:
>
> ```
> class Foo
>   def initialize(val)
>     return nil if val == 0
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> I know in C/C++/Java/C#, we cant return a value in a constructor.
>
> But I'm wondering whether it is possible in Ruby.

There is no such thing as a *constructor* in Ruby. In Ruby, there are only methods, and they can return values.

The problem you are seeing is simply that you want to change the return value of one method but you are overriding a different method. If you want to change the return value of method `bar`, you should override `bar`, not some other method.

If you want to change the behavior of `Foo::new`, then you should change `Foo::new`:

```
class Foo
  def self.new(val)
    return nil if val.zero?
    super
  end
end
```

Note, however, that this is a *really bad idea*, since it violates the contract of `new`, which is to return a fully initialized, fully functioning instance of the class.

Comment: `self` *is* `Foo` there. Try `class Foo; p self end # => Foo`

Comment: Instead of simply stating that something is _bad_, would you care to offer the OP a better designed solution? Perhaps something like Metz's [after_initialize](https://amcaplan.ninja/blog/2014/05/30/how-to-stay-classy-with-ruby-variables/) pattern? A validator? Etc.

Answer (score 51):

There are important differences between the two methods.

`new` is a *class* method, which generally creates an instance of the class (this deals with the tricky stuff like allocating memory that Ruby shields you from so you don't have to get too dirty).

Then, `initialize`, an *instance* method, tells the object to set its internal state up according to the parameters requested.

Either of these can be overridden depending on what you want. For example, `Foo.new` might actually create and return an instance of `FooSubclass` if it needs to be clever enough to do that.

However, often it's better to delegate use cases like these to other class methods which are more explicit about what they do, for example `Foo.relating_to(bar)`. Breaking other peoples expectations about what methods like `new` should do will confuse people more than it will help them in the long run.

As an example, look at the implementation of `Singleton`, a module which allows only one instance of a particular class to exist. It makes the `new` method private, and exposes an `instance` method which either returns the existing instance of the object, or calls `new` if it hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 8):

You can something like this:

```
class Foo

  def self.init(val)
    new(val) unless val == 0
  end

  def initialize(val)
    #...
  end
end
```

Example of usage:

```
obj = Foo.init(0)
 => nil
obj = Foo.init(5)
 => #<Foo:0x00000002970a98>
```

Comment: In your example does this call new also?

Comment: If you mean the example when we call `init` with 0, then no, the `new`  won't be invoked.

Answer (score 5):

Wanting to do

```
class Foo
  def initialize(val)
    return nil if val == 0
  end
end
```

would make for inconsistent code.

If you had

```
class Foo
  def initialize(val)
    return nil if val == 0
    @val = val
    @bar = 42
  end
end
```

what would you want to get back if you did `Foo.new(1)`? Would you want `42` (the return value for `Foo#initialize`), or a `foo` object? If you want a `foo` object for `Foo.new(1)`, then why would you expect `return nil` to make `Foo.new(0)` return nil?

Answer (score -2):

It is solved by simply creating an object variable like this:

```
class Foo
   def initialize(val)
       @val = val
       return nil if @val == 0
   end
end
obj = Foo.new(0)

Output:-
=>#<Foo:0x1243b8 @val=0>
```

The output varies in different computers.