# Where is the Model.new method defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am trying to find the source of the models' `new` method. I tried to use [`source_location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location) with ActiveRecord::Base.new, and with Widget.new (where Widget is a model), and do

```
find . -name *rb -exec grep -il "def new$" {} \;
```

inside the activerecord gem directory but had no luck.

Comment: The `new` method is the constructor, in any case you should be looking for the `initialize` method of `ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Ruby object is instantiated via `.new`, it generally runs the object's `initialize` method.  This is defined on `Class` by default:

```
1.9.3p327 :002 > ActiveRecord::Base.method(:new)
=> #<Method: Class#new>
```

If you want to create a custom initializer for a Rails model, simply define an `initialize` method.  Note that there are some caveats to this, because `initialize` isn't necessarily always called by ActiveRecord.  You may be better off adding an [after_initialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback instead.

See [How to find where a method is defined at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime) and [In Ruby, what's the relationship between 'new' and 'initialize'? How to return nil while initializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383535/in-ruby-whats-the-relationship-between-new-and-initialize-how-to-return-n) for some more helpful information about finding where methods are defined and how `new` and `initialize` are related.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also tell me where Model.save is located or how to find it?