# Why does a method not return the last statement when we call 'super' inside?

Tags: ruby

The return value of a method is the value of its last statement. This means that `Myclass.new` following the definition below of the `initialize` method with `super` inside:

```
class Myclass < String
  def initialize(arg)
    super(arg.to_s)
    "something"
  end
end
```

should return `"something"`. But it returns `"test"` instead:

```
Myclass.new("test") # => "test"
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe it's beacause initialize and new are not the same function ?

Comment: The contract of `new` is to return the new object that was created (allocated then initialized). If it returned the result value of when it calls `initialize`, it would obviously not do that. (Unless you ended all implementations of `initialize` with `return self` which would be fantastically annoying.)

Comment: Also, the documentation for `new` literally says the above. (Quote: "Calls `allocate` to create a new object of *class*'s class, then invokes that object’s `initialize` method, passing it *args*.")

Comment: this is also a good explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383535/in-ruby-whats-the-relationship-between-new-and-initialize-how-to-return-n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class method `new`

1. creates a new instance, then
2. calls the instance method `initialize` on the instance created, which may return whatever, as in your example, then
3. returns the instance created.

The return value from `initialize` to `new` has no effect on the return value from `new`.

Answer (score 4):

You're not calling `initialize`, you're calling `new`. The `initialize` method is essentially a hook that is executed when you create a new object, but it is typically never called directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the return value of your `initialize` method, you need to call your `initialize` method. If you call a completely different method, it is only normal that you would get a completely different return value.