# Ruby on Rails Classes

Tags: ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-4

Does a class in RoR automatically initiate the first method when a new object of that class is created?

```
class User
 attr_accessor :name, :email

 def initialize(attributes = {})
  @name  = attributes[:name]
  @email = attributes[:email]
 end

 def formatted_email
  "#{@name} <#{@email}>"
 end
end
```

Say I create a new User like this

```
connor = User.new(name: "Connor B", email: "CB@example.com")
```

How does it know to automatically start the first method but the second method only works when called upon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the first method that's called automatically, it's that `new` calls `initialize`, which happens to be the first method in most code that you see. However, you could put `initialize` anywhere in the class definition and `new` would still call the `initialize` method.

If there is no `initialize` method explicitly defined then a default one will be called. Also, this is a Ruby behavior, **not** a Ruby on Rails behavior, just to clarify.

Here's a [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383535/in-ruby-whats-the-relationship-between-new-and-initialize-how-to-return-n) that you might find enlightening. The top answer shows an example that explains it in a bit more detail, and digs into more of what's actually going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So every class by default has an initialize method.

Comment: You can think of it that way, sure. There's some more detail in this Q&A (which I've added to my answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383535/in-ruby-whats-the-relationship-between-new-and-initialize-how-to-return-n

Answer (score 1):

Ruby automatically calls the `initialize` method when a new object of that class is created.

`new` calls the `initialize` method.

#### [Reference](http://www.rubyist.net/%7Eslagell/ruby/objinitialization.html)

Comment: Is that due to some ruby on rails built in method or could initialize be called anything. I am confused as to why it calls that method

Comment: I guess it is `instance` not `object`.

Comment: It must be called `initialize`. That is what "new" does.