# When creating a new object in ruby, what method does it call first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: code block]

[image: code block]

When i create the object as soon above, is the method initliase called first?
In PHP, we have something called the constructor with run first whenever an object is created, what if there is more than 1 method in the class, which method is called first in ruby?

Thanks.

Comment: This stackoveflow site makes it so hard to learn, what is this stuff about not having enough reputation to post more than 2 links. Absolutely rubbish site, i just want to learn. Not enough reputation to use more keywords. If there is any troubles you should just ban the user, you make it difficult to learn.

Comment: There are plenty of books and  tutorials available (interactive ones even). If you don't like the site or its rules don't use it no point in complaining in your own post. Please see this SO post to answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383535/in-ruby-whats-the-relationship-between-new-and-initialize-how-to-return-n

Comment: Ruby, just like PHP, is text-based. You should therefore post your code as text.

Comment: @zenarthra, just write the code contained in the images in your question. Just indent it with four spaces, and you'll be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

[`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) is just a normal method like any other method. It looks a bit like this, although in most implementations it is actually not written in Ruby:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    new_obj = allocate

    new_obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    # actually, `initialize` is private, so it's more like this instead:
    # new_obj.__send__(:initialize, *args, &block)

    return new_obj
  end
end
```

The documentation also says it clearly:

> ## `new(args, …)` → `obj`
>
> Calls `allocate` to create a new object of *class*’s class, then invokes that object’s `initialize` method, passing it *args*. This is the method that ends up getting called whenever an object is constructed using `.new`.

Here's the source code for `Class#new` in the various implementations:

- [Rubinius](http://rubinius.com/): [`machine/builtin/class.cpp`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/machine/builtin/class.cpp#L112-L118)
- [JRuby](http://JRuby.org/): [`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyClass.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyClass.java#L988-L1024)
- [Topaz](http://topazruby.com/): [`topaz/objects/classobject.py`](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/blob/master/topaz/objects/classobject.py#L127-L131)
- [MagLev](http://maglev.github.io/): [`src/kernel/bootstrap/Class.rb`](https://github.com/MagLev/maglev/blob/master/src/kernel/bootstrap/Class.rb#L94-L99)
- YARV: [`object.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L1874-L1883) (BTW, you will notice that this method is defined in `object.c`, not in `class.c`. This is one of those reasons I prefer *not* to look at YARV for implementations details, and instead look at Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, or Topaz. They are just much better organized.)

Answer (score 0):

the `initialize` method is called whenever you call `new`.

Any other methods declared in that class should be called in your code.

For example:

```
class Example
  def initialize
    #some initialization code here
    puts "initialize method has just been called"
  end

  def foo
    #some foo code
    puts "this is the foo method"
  end 
end
```

then, in your code:

```
my_obj = Example.new #initialize method will be called here

my_obj.foo #now the foo method will be called
```

That's about it, good luck!

Comment: This is inaccurate. `my_obj = new Example` is invalid syntax in Ruby, it would have to be `my_obj = Example.new`